# Redirect without www to an image

Tags: web, redirect, imageurl

Here are that i have in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this not work for me.

I want to put to an URL
[www.sitename.com/images/image-name.jpg](http://www.sitename.com/images/image-name.jpg)
and have in output the redirection to
sitename.com/images/image-name.jpg

The main idea - no any 'www' in an url of images on site.

How can i proceed?

Thanks to all.

I have tried several directives in .htaccess, but no succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Second condition seems wrong as it is excluding **images** folder from the rule. You need to include the **images** folder instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

also if you want to force all other addresses to have www (except images) you may also add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```